# Including another MySQL class in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress installation, say in localhost/blog/ path.

I also have another custom CMS installed in the root folder like localhost/ .

I want to include my CMS' MySQL class into the blog's installation, so in the blog theme's header.php, i include like so:

```
<?php
global $site_config, $_db // $_db is my CMS' equivalent to $wpdb;

include_once("../includes/class.query.php");
?>
```

I am able to access my CMS' database in the Wordpress blog.

However, some variables in the Wordpress like the author of the article went missing. Calling functions like "get_the_author_meta('ID')", "the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail')" returns empty string. Also gallery posted in posts gone missing too. Other content like the post content are working fine.

The content of the 'class.query.php' above is rather simple. I have narrowed it down to these few lines:

```
function connect()
{
    if ($this->mysql_link = @mysql_connect($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass))
    {
        if (!mysql_select_db($this->dbase))  // <---- this is the line that screwed up the integration
        {
....
```

I wonder if someone knows what's going on here. Why only some Wordpress functions are affected?

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds like a painful exercise. What benefit do you anticipate gaining by trying to replace all of Wordpress' DB access logic?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using Namespaces in your custom class to avoid any clashes with existing WP functionality.

Comment: @MikeBrant, I am not trying to replace $wpdb. I intend to share some data from my own CMS on the blog itself. My intention is to call a function from my CMS that returns the whole site's header (menu, user data, etc). Hence i need to be able to access my CMS' functions, which needs the DB too. Makes sense?

Comment: @cillosis, i tried using namespace for my class, the result is still the same. :(

Comment: maybe the included class points to an other database? and once its loaded (the line you highlighted), the mysql connection of wordpress points to said database too?

Comment: @Andreas, shouldnt that be a different link to the MySQL? Because the CMS and the wordpress' class connect separately. Is there a limit to have only one link to MySQL? But that said, why other Wordpress content works. Another hint, "get_the_author_meta()" works fine on an article page, but returns empty string on blog main page.

Comment: you could test this hypothesis by simply listing the tables using [SHOW TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html).  the things is that using mysql_connect as shown in your code sample will **not** automatically mean that a new connection is opened.  if there is an existing open connection on the database, then this connection will be returned. see the description of parameter `new_link` [here](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)